# Techniques to Prove a Map Open or Closed

Tags: general-topology, open-map, closed-map

I've been finding it hard to verify that given maps are open or closed in practice. For example, in his discussion of the Mobius bundle, Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* says without justification that if $E$ is the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the equivalence relation $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ if and only if $(x',y') = (x + n, (-1)^n y)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $q : \mathbb{R}^2 \to E$ is the quotient map, then the restriction of $q$ to $[0,1] \times \mathbb{R}$ is closed and therefore also a quotient map.

Since he doesn't go into much detail on this, I assume that verifying that the restriction is closed isn't hard, but I can't seem to find any way to do it without delving deep into the weeds and proving it straight from the definition. In general I have trouble proving that maps are open or closed; are there any tricks or overall methods I should be aware of?

Comment: any restriction of a closed map is closed

Comment: Any continuous map from a compact topological space to a Hausdorff space is closed. Also, any [proper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) continuous map between locally compact Hausdorff spaces is closed. The latter fact and the Heine-Borel theorem are useful for studying continuous maps between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalence relation says $(x,y)\sim(x',y')$ iff $x'-x\in\Bbb{Z}$ and $y'=\pm y$ which implies $E=[0,1)\times(\Bbb{R}^+\cup\{0\})$.

Denote the restricted domain by $D=[0,1]\times\Bbb{R}$, then
consider the restricted map $q^*:D\to E$ defined explicitly by,

$$
q^*(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
(x,|y|) &\text{ if }x\in[0,1)\\
(0,|y|) &\text{ if }x=1\\
\end{cases}
$$

The coordinate function for $y$ is obviously closed.

Take a closed set $U\subset D$ then the $x$-coordinate of elements in $U$ must take values in $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$, while the $x$-coordinate for the image must take values in $[a,b]$ **OR** $[a,1)\cup\{0\}$, both of which situations are closed since $[a,1)\cup\{0\}=([a,1]\cap [0,1))\cup(\{0\}\cap [0,1))$ (subspace). Because this is true for every closed set in $D$, so $q^*$ is closed.

---

Add one method (according to the note from hunter):

We can also prove $q:\Bbb{R}^2\to E$ is closed. Take a closed set $V\subset\Bbb{R}^2$ and denote the range for the $x$-coordinate of elements in $V$ by $V_x=[m,n]$. Then, 
$$q(V)_x=
\begin{cases}
[m_1,n_1]\subset[0,1) &\text{ if } \Bbb{Z}\cap[m,n]=\varnothing\\
[|m|-\lfloor|m|\rfloor,1)\cup[0,|n|-\lfloor|n|\rfloor] &\text{ if } \Bbb{Z}\cap[m,n]\neq\varnothing
\end{cases}
$$
So, $q$ is closed, and so does $q^*$ by restricting its domain, using the properties of a subspace.

---

General tips:

This is hard to generalize a tip for every situations, but the ideas are similar. I'm sure that professors have deeper understandings and more methods than I do.

1. To prove a map is open(closed), we can test the basis or subbasis elements (or closed sets/ complement of open sets). Sometimes it's easy, if we're given a homeomorphism, then it is immediately open and closed.
2. However, continuity doesn't imply anything about closedness or openness, e.g.
   $$
   f(x)=
   \begin{cases}
   x, & x\ge0\\
   0, & x\le0
   \end{cases}
   $$
   $f$ is clearly continuous, but not open since $(-2,2)\mapsto[0,2)$ given the euclidean topology. Another one is $g(x)=|x|$, it is closed but not open since $(-1,2)\mapsto[0,2)$. Besides that, there exists continuous maps that are not open nor closed.

But the two explicit maps mentioned above are open when we're given the lower-limit topology. So,

3. Be aware of the topology. Normally we use the euclidean topology when we refer to the topological space $\Bbb{R}^n$ without any further condition about its topology.

---

I Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm aware that you asked for general methods, here is an elementary approach (partly because I haven't come across or figured out a straightforward abstract argument yet).

Let's denote the restriction of $q$ to $S=[0,1]\times\mathbb R$ by $q_S$, so that the symbol $q$ is reserved for the map with domain $\mathbb R^2$. Let $A\subset [0,1]\times\mathbb R$ be closed. We want to show that $q_S(A)=q(A)$ is closed. By definition of the quotient topology, $q(A)$ is closed iff
$$
q^{-1}(q(A))=\{(x+n,(-1)^n y):(x,y)\in A\}
$$
is closed. Since $\mathbb R^2$ is first countable, checking that $q^{-1}(q(A))$ is closed is equivalent to checking that for each convergent sequence $(w_k)_k$ in $q^{-1}(q(A))$ its limit $w$ lies in $q^{-1}(q(A))$. By the description above we can write $w_k=(x_k+n_k,(-1)^{n_k}y_k$) with $(x_k,y_k)\in A$. We have $w=(x,y)\in [m,m+1]\times [n,n+1]$ for some $m,n\in\mathbb Z$.

We consider two cases.

Case 1: If $x\in (m,m+1)$ then we know that eventually $w_k=(x_k+m,(-1)^my_k)$ for each $k$, and hence $(x_k,y_k)$ converges to $(x-m,(-1)^m y)\in A$ since $A\subset S$ is closed, and therefore $w=(x,y)\in q^{-1}(q(A))$.

Case 2: If $x=m$ or $x=m+1$, then we know that there exists a subsequence $x_{k_i}$ of $x_k$ such that either $x_{k_i}=0$ for all $i$ or $x_{k_i}=1$ for all $i$. In either case we have $(x_{k_i}+n_{k_i},(-1)^{n_{k_i}}y_{k_i})=(x_{k_i}+m',(-1)^{m'}y_{k_i})$ for all $i$ (with $m'=m$ or $m'=m+1$). By a similar argument as above it follows that $w\in q^{-1}(q(A))$.